# Grab files with current year and last 5 years in the name and concatenate into 1 dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that will concatenate files going back a certain number of full years and also include the current year file. I have all of the files named the same except for the year at the end (e.g. Data2010, Data2011...Data2018)

Right now I have it set up to pull all the files and concatenate them into one dataframe, but I'm not sure how to write the function that pulls only certain years based on the current year and a number I provide.

*Edit: is it possible to write the function so that this will always work without making edits to the file as the year changes? So the function would read the current year through datetime or something and know what the last 5 years are?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
import glob

qms = os.path.join('X:', 'JY', 'Analyst', 'Data')
today = datetime.datetime.today()

#Pulling all files and concatenating, needs to pull only last 5 + current 
warranty_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(qms, '*.csv'))
warranty_list = []
for file_ in warranty_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    warranty_list.append(df)
warranty = pd.concat(warranty_list)

# def get_warranty(years): #want this to be the start of function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make specific selections, `glob` also allows you to do this.

I made a folder with 3 text files labeled, `Data2010, Data2011, Data2013`, and I can pick all the files after 2010 like so:

```
files = glob.glob("/path/to/folder/"+"Data201[1-9].txt")
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

In other words, you should be able to use `regex` to further customize file selection. Once you select the right number of files you can then concatenate them into a `pd.DataFrame`.

Grabbing the current and last five years in my example above would look like this, `"Data201[3-8].txt"`. If there's some text before that portion of the filename, add an asterisk `*`: `"*Data201[3-8].txt"`. Let me know if something isn't clear!

EDIT: OP asked for an automated way to select their files based on current year. Here's a method that does so. Test it out!

```
path = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\test\\"
def get_files(path,n=5):
    files = [] #list to append to
    current_year = datetime.datetime.today().year #current year
    last_n_years = [str(current_year-i) for i in range(0,n+1)] #list last 5 years
    for year in last_n_years:
        files_ = glob.glob(path + "*Data%s.csv" % year) #grab csv files per year
        if files_: #if files_ is not []
            for f in files_: #for file in files_
                files.append(f) #append each file
    return files

files = get_files(path,n=5)
print(files)
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping there was a way to pull in the current year and then automatically go back 5 years so the file wouldn't need editing as the years change, not sure if it's possible.

Comment: You can definitely make it so that the filenames include the current year, just define a filename pattern that updates with respect to the current datetime prior to using `glob`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not being clear. I was the function to know what year it is by looking at that day's date and go back 5 years. This way I don't have to change the numbers in glob ever, even as I get more years of data.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, give me a bit to edit my answer to show you.

Comment: @JordanR let me know if this updated answer helps you out. You can play around with the function if you don't like my formatting etc., but it should work as is, you just need to change it to only capture `.csv` files.

Comment: Actually, there's a dumb error in the code that I didn't notice because of the fake data directory I set up - let me fix it really quick.